# Add extra parameters to return from facebook auth dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

How can I have the facebook auth dialog to return me an extra parameter upon success from the auth dialog?

To be more specific, I want to add a "returnUrl" that is the page that a user tried to access before being authenticated.

I tried adding as a querystring parameter to the url set in redirect_uri but it doesn't work when I try to get the token later from oauth/access_token.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a query string parameter to the `redirect_uri` should work; I have done it in the past. Just make sure you pass the *exact* same URL (including the query string parameter) to `oauth/access_token`.